# spreadsheet "input form" on "frontpage" that saves input to specific tab

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Imagine a spreadsheet, could be Excel or Google Spreadsheet.

Given I have multiple tabs, each to represent some data I want to save. There could be 60-80 tabs.

Now, I want an easy way to input data into that spreadsheet, so I imagine having a dropdown on some sort of frontpage where I can select where to direct my input.

It could look like this:

```
   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                    │
   │                                                    │
   │           Selected                                 │
   │           sheet     Value                          │
   │          ┌──────▼  ┌─────────────┐ ┌──────┐        │
   │          │sheet1│  │             │ │ Save │        │
   │          │sheet2│  └─────────────┘ └──────┘        │
   │          │sheet3│                                  │
   │          └──────┘                                  │
   │                                                    │
   │                                                    │
   │                                                    │
   ├───────────┬────────┬───────┬─────────┬───┬───┬──┬──┤
   │ Frontpage │ sheet1 │sheet2 │ sheet3  │ … │ … │… │… │
   └───────────┴────────┴───────┴─────────┴───┴───┴──┴──┘
```

Clearly I could build a web application and use a real database, but I want to explore what is possible with just a spreadsheet or similar.

Given I have selected the spread sheet name in the dropdown and given I write a value in the next field, how do I "save" that value in the correct tab?

Comment: you have posted twice the same problem, I propose you to delete one of them

Comment: @mike: I have not posted same problem twice. This Q is about the saving of input to custom tab. Other question is about how to show contents from other tabs in a dropdown.

I deliberately split the question so that each could handle a separate thread.

Comment: I apologize! you are right. So why this post has been closed by Player0?

Comment: I will answer to this question using the other post.

Comment: Take both answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71275544/15019380